# Vue3 build wrapper for legacy application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a question related to Vue3 that I could use some help with.

I've upgraded a large Vue2 application to Vue3, and part of the challenge is that when it was Vue2, it had a command to compile a "wrapper." This wrapper was intended to add new functionality into the legacy application until we can complete the full conversion process for other reasons. The legacy application has its own Vue2 components that we're trying to avoid upgrading since upgrading from Vue2 to Vue3 can be a challenging process.

While I've successfully compiled the Vue3 wrapper, I've encountered issues when placing the files into the legacy application. Has anyone else faced this issue or have any advice on how to resolve it? At this point, I'm not sure what else to try to get it to work.

this is the package.json script I'm running

```
WRAPPER_BUILD=true vue-cli-service build && cpx './lib_dist/*' ../legacy/webroot/vue_dist -C -v
```

This is my Vue3 vue.config.js file

the idea is that this could build for the wrapper. Then once its done building use `cpx` to copy the files into the correct place in legacy in production these files are uploaded to S3.

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

const {
  WRAPPER_BUILD = false
} = process.env

const wrapperBuild = WRAPPER_BUILD === 'true'

console.log({
  WRAPPER_BUILD,
  wrapperBuild,
})

module.exports = {
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, wrapperBuild ? 'lib_dist' : 'dist'),

  transpileDependencies: true,
  productionSourceMap: false,
  publicPath: wrapperBuild ? '/vue_dist/' : '/pages/',

  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: 'all',
    https: true,
  },
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: "@import '@/assets/styles/scss/main.scss';",
      },
    },
  },
  configureWebpack: (config) => {
    const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

    config.devtool = isProduction && wrapperBuild ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map'

    if (isProduction && wrapperBuild && !wrapperBuild) {
      config.optimization = {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
          new TerserPlugin({
            test: /\.(js|ts|vue)(\?.*)?$/i,
            extractComments: true,
            terserOptions: {
              compress: {
                drop_console: true,
                dead_code: true,
                drop_debugger: true,
              },
            },
          }),
        ],
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'all',
          minSize: 20000,
          maxSize: 0,
          minChunks: 1,
          maxAsyncRequests: 30,
          maxInitialRequests: 30,
          automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
          enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
          cacheGroups: {
            defaultVendors: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              priority: -10,
              reuseExistingChunk: true,
            },
            default: {
              minChunks: 2,
              priority: -20,
              reuseExistingChunk: true,
            },
          },
        },
      }
    } else {
      config.optimization = {
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'all',
          cacheGroups: {
            default: false,
            vendors: false,
          },
        },
      }

      config.entry = './src/static_app_wrapper/main.js'

      config.output = {
        ...config.output,
        filename: !wrapperBuild ? 'main-[contenthash].js' : 'main-wrapper-[contenthash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name]-[contenthash].js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
      }
    }
  },
}
```

**Edited:** during the build, it generates chunks, but the optimize step puts them all in one file; I have a specific use case for that. Just wanted to point that out in case anybody notices.

**Edited:** Even if anybody has a different approach this is what we came up with to solve this problem.